# ionic v1 - disable swipe of one list to propagate to parent list

Tags: ionic-framework

I have the following  construct in an ionic v1 `collection-repeat` list: (simplified to show the essence)

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item collection repeat="event in events">
           <!-- scrolling list of alarm frames inside an event-->
           <ion-scroll direction="x" overflow-scroll="false">
              <span ng-repeat="alarm in alarm_images">
                   <img src="alarm.src"></img>
              </span>
           </ion-scroll>
         <ion-option-button>Flag</ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

What I'd like for to happen is when you swipe left and right on the alarm frames, it should NOT result in the option swipe (Flag/Unflag) to show. But if you swipe elsewhere in the item, it should result in the option swipe.

I haven't found a way to prevent the swipe on the alarm frames to propagate to the list. Is there a way to do it?

Here is the currently undesirable visual:

http://gph.is/2ism1cc

I tried this - while the handler is called, it doesn't stop any propagation

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" overflow-scroll="false"  on-swipe-left="alarmSwipe($event)">
```

and

```
$scope.alarmSwipe = function(e)
{

  //alert ("HERE");
  console.log ("HERE");
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault(); // tried adding this too
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the event to propagate to parent.

Try something like below ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054687/prevent-swipe-events-when-interacting-with-elements-on-a-page)) :

```
$('#child-element').bind('swipeLeft swipeRight', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried something similar  and it did not work so far - original post updated